# What would be necessary to use a Rasperry pi zero W as a wifi to usb-C gateway for Android Auto?

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, android-auto

As many new infotainment systems in cars support Android Auto, but not wireless. I was wondering if I could program something that would allow to use a cheap Raspberry Pi as a gateway. Effectively emulating a phone on the usb side, but recieving the real data from a real phone through wifi. I'm a programmer, but I don't understand the inner workings of Android's USB system to know if it's possible or not (with or without root).

If I know where to start, I can create an open source project on github. I have experience in both a little Android programming as a few languages like .net core or python to make it work on the raspberries side.

```
android phone <--wifi--> raspberry pi <--usb--> car system
```

Like for example Renault easy link that is in my Renault Twingo (2019).

Comment: Dont runs Android on the raspberry, just use Raspbian and use it to provide a Wifi access point plus forward the traffic the car system (however the car system works). On the raspberry you just need `dnsmasq` and `hostapd` to provide the Wifi access point (there are dozens of tutorials on the net.

Comment: Yes I was looking for forwarding the data itself as if the phone was connected by usb

Comment: I don't think that this is possible without having to build a totally new Android system. Especially the part "connecting an Android phone via Wifi to whatever but the device (and all apps) thinks it is connected via USB".

Comment: Small update: there are now [a few devices](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/carsifi/carsifi-wireless-android-auto-adapter) that do exactly as I described. I'm glad I bought one for €120 instead of spending months and probably more money than that to make an inferior version myself.